# c# set ListBox to RTL

Tags: c#, listbox, right-to-left

As an attempt to color text in ListBox i found this guide [C# : change listbox items color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896151/c-sharp-change-listbox-items-color) (i am using windows forms application on visual studio 2012).
The code is working but the problem is that i want to use the textbox in a Right to Left mode, but when i change it in the ListBox settings it does not work, so i assume that it needs to be changed in the code somehow, this is what i need your help for.
Thank you very much!
Alon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your y position is 0, so everytime you insert a message it's on the left side.
To put it on the right side you have recalculate the postion.

Look at the following example.

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    MyListBoxItem item = listBox1.Items[e.Index] as MyListBoxItem; // Get the current item and cast it to MyListBoxItem
    if (item != null)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString( // Draw the appropriate text in the ListBox
                   item.Message, // The message linked to the item
                   listBox1.Font, // Take the font from the listbox
                   new SolidBrush(item.ItemColor), // Set the color 
                   width - 4, // X pixel coordinate
                   e.Index * listBox1.ItemHeight,
                   new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft)); // Y pixel coordinate.  Multiply the index by the ItemHeight defined in the listbox.                
    }
    else
    {
        // The item isn't a MyListBoxItem, do something about it
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, if the sentence is long it shows the last couple of letters on the right side, otherwise it doesn't show anything

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.horizontalscrollbar.aspx explains how do you get an horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Excellent! It's working but not perfect, can you think of any way that will make the text in the ListBox sharper? it seems fuzzy...
edit:if i put the scroll bar always on in the properties it is showen but unactive... you can't click on it

Comment: At first found a better solution for the RTL problem. `e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;` is for the fuzzy problem. With the scrollbar look at other questions or open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

A list box is natively left-justified and you cannot change this in the UIR editor. You can apply the appropriate justification elements while creating the string to pass to the list box: see the online help for Item Label parameter of the `InsertListItem` function. All escape codes are to be applied to every line that you insert into the list box; there is no way to apply a default formatting style to the control.

Comment: I didn't really understood your answer... what exactly should i do to make it RTL (if even possible)?