# How to change text color of an item in a ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a `ListBox` with several items, also I have a **connect** button. On the connect button `_Click` event i am connecting each item to the server.

I want to change the text color of the item to green after the Connect button has been clicked. And red for those for whom Connect button have not been clicked and Vice Versa.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Way to color parts of the Listbox/ListView line in C# WinForms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268113/way-to-color-parts-of-the-listbox-listview-line-in-c-sharp-winforms)

Comment: Answer is on:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896151/c-sharp-change-listbox-items-color "C# : change listbox items color"

Comment: i wrote the DrawItem Event but am confused from where to call these two.`host_listbox_new.DrawMode = OwnerDrawFixed;
    host_listbox_new.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(this.listBox1_DrawItem);`

Comment: you can see thi topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896151/c-sharp-change-listbox-items-color

Answer (score 4):

Use owner-draw mode of the ListBox. That will solve your problem. Select your ListBox in design-mode and change `DrawMode` property to `OwnerDrawFixed`. Now attach a handler to `DrawItem` event and then use `Graphics` class's methods to draw your string in any color or font you like. An example of what you need to do in `DrawItem` would be:

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), listBox1.Font, Brushes.Green, e.Bounds);
}
```

Comment: how to attach a handler to DrawItem event and then use Graphics class's methods??

Comment: doubleclick the event in the action tag of the property editor of the listbox

Comment: @MaxCarroll: Yes. However, the property name there is `OwnerDraw` and not `DrawMode`. Also note that unlike ListBox, a ListView raises separate events for `DrawItem` and `DrawSubItem`.